# CoreData Arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsarray

Currently I need to set up a database that uses the following structure.

- Item 1

  - Object A

    - Stuff A1
    - Stuff A2
    - Stuff A3
  - Object B

    - Stuff B1

My first thought was to create 3 entities, one for "Item", "Object", and "Stuff", then have an array in each.
So each "Item" would have an array containing the "objects", and each object with an array of "stuff."

Would this be a good approach? If not, what would be a more correct and efficient way of accomplishing the same task?

Comment: You should use **to-many relationship** for that.

Comment: Awesome, just got it working. If you add this as an answer with a short description I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theese situations, when you have 2 entities and you want to have a *relation* between them, you should try out **CoreData's relationships**. In this case you should use *to-many relationship*.

PS: Don't forget to select your relationship delete rule! :)

Answer (score 4):

Your approach to create 3 entities is the right way. The connections between these entities is what Core Data refer to as *relations*. You need to take note that Core Data only handles unordered relations. So *Object A* will not get an `NSArray` of *Stuff*, it will have a `NSSet` of *Stuff*.

If ordering is required then you need to use an attribute of the sub-entity for sorting, and fetch these objects using an `NSFetchRequest`. For example sorting on some "name" or "date" attribute.

Comment: I shouldn't run into any issues if I create a new transformable attribute and store for an NSSet?

Comment: You can use any class that conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol as a transformable attribute. All collection classes are coding compliant, just make sure the objects you stick in them and use for keys are as well.

Comment: Well any other class can be used for a transformable attribute as well, if you implement a `NSValueTransformer` subclass that can convert instances to and from `NSData`. But that is a pretty complex task, sticking with `NSCoding` compliant classes covers 99% of everything needed.

Comment: Cool, thanks for you help. I just got it working with a one-to-many relationship.